# how to do this in laravel - single query

Tags: laravel

The below query collects the count as described earlier. I require the output in the correct array format for the following code.

As seen below output, there are duplicate lines in the array. How can the duplicates be combined to a single entry.

```
  $query1 = DB::table('tb_addquestion')
                        ->leftJoin('tb_user', 'tb_user.UserId', 'tb_addquestion.UserId')
                        ->groupBy('tb_addquestion.UserId')
                        ->having('count', '>', $minimum)
                        ->having('count', '<', $maximum)
                        ->select('tb_addquestion.UserId', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS count,"questions" AS type'))
                        ->get();
        $query2 = DB::table('tb_answer')
                        ->leftJoin('tb_user', 'tb_user.UserId', 'tb_answer.UserId')
                        ->groupBy('tb_answer.UserId')
                        ->having('count', '>', $minimum_ans)
                        ->having('count', '<', $maximum_ans)
                        ->select('tb_answer.UserId', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS count,"answers" AS type'))
                        ->get();
    
          $users = $query1->union($query2);
    
          $r = 0;
          $user_details= array();
          foreach($users as $user){
    
            $results = TBUser::select("tb_user.*","tb_addquestion.UserId","tb_addquestion.Timestamp","tb_answer.Timestamp","tb_answer.UserId")
                                            ->leftjoin('tb_addquestion','tb_user.UserId', '=', 'tb_addquestion.UserId')
                                            ->leftjoin('tb_answer','tb_user.UserId', '=', 'tb_answer.UserId')
                                            ->leftjoin('tb_selectsubject','tb_user.UserId', '=', 'tb_selectsubject.UserId')
                                            ->where('tb_user.UserId',$user->UserId)
                                            ->where('tb_user.Gender',$gender)
                                            ->where('tb_user.Country',$country)
                                            ->where('tb_user.Grade',$grade)
                                            ->whereBetween('tb_addquestion.Timestamp', 
     [$dayStart_qs,$dayEnd_qs])
                                            ->whereBetween('tb_answer.Timestamp', [$dayStart_ans,$dayEnd_ans])
                                            ->where('tb_selectsubject.SubjectId',$subject_id)
                                            ->where(function ($query) use ($dayStart,$dayEnd){
                                          $query->whereBetween('tb_user.Timestamp', [$dayStart,$dayEnd])
                                                ->orWhereBetween('tb_user.Timestamp2', [$dayStart,$dayEnd]);
                                          })
                                            ->get();
    
                     $user_details[$r] = $user;
                     $user_details[$r]->results = $results;
    
    
                  $r++;
         }
```

OUTPUT:

```
array:224 [▼
  0 => {#1164 ▶}
  1 => {#372 ▶}
  2 => {#1098 ▶}
  3 => {#1309 ▶}
  4 => {#1099 ▼
    +"UserId": 184
    +"count": 3
    +"type": "questions"
    +"results": Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1549 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => App\TBUser {#1559 ▼
          #table: "tb_user"
          #fillable: array:41 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:42 [▶]
          #original: array:42 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #classCastCache: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
        1 => App\TBUser {#1557 ▶}
        2 => App\TBUser {#1561 ▶}
      ]
    }
  }
  5 => {#1060 ▶}
```

As seen above, there are duplicate lines in the array. How can the duplicates be combined to a single entry.

Comment: Please read the documentation. This is well documented. After you gave it a try, come here and post the code you're stuck with. Please note that you don't add variables to a query this way to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Can you Update Your Table relationships as well so that we can help You..

Answer (score 0):

We Really Don't know how  is your relationships are defined, so I assume that you could get  result by following this example

```
 $result = YourQuestionModel::with('answer', function($query) user ($request){
 if($request->filled('date_filter')){
   $query->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::parse($request->date_from)
           ->startOfDay(), Carbon::parse($request->date_to)->endOfDay()]);
)->where('user_id', $userID);
$result->get();
```

You can get count using `count()` in the result